# SELECT 5 newsid FROM all categories except last newsid

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in which I add news. I need to show only 5 news from the 6 latest categories except last news for that 6 categories

I know how to show all news without last news.

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsid != (SELECT MAX(newsid) FROM news) ORDER BY newsid DESC;
```

but when i try to add AND condition

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE category = '$category' AND newsid != (SELECT MAX(newsid) FROM news) ORDER BY newsid DESC LIMIT 5
```

it shows 5 latest news from categories

Picture of the database.

[image]

Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add an offset:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE category = '$category'
ORDER BY newsid DESC
LIMIT 1, 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much - you really helped me a lot!